# How to create dynamic table in html and angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to present in Html a dynamic table that I don't know what is the template of each row:
Some times it contains 2 columns, sometimes 4...

I need something like this:

```
    <div>
   <h1>Angular HTML Table Example</h1>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>#ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray">
            <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
           
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div
```

And instead of:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray">
        <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.address }}</td></tr>
```

somethong like:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray">
<ngFor="let property of item.structure>  
            <td>{{ property }}</td>
```

Do you have any advice for me?

Thanks

Comment: The `*ngFor` should be inside of the `td` tag so that it creates a cell for each column. Furthermore you should iterate over a `Object.keys(item)` so you can do `*ngFor="let key of keys"` ... `item[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get keys of list item by using below code and render header column

```
Object.keys(list);
```

This is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbhjm4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.ts) code

You can see required code in Product component file. I hope it works for you scenario

Comment: Should I write it in typescript? or HTML?

Comment: Just change the html code to this, <tr *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray">
<ngFor="let property of Object.keys(item)>  
            <td>{{ item[property] }}</td>

Comment: you should write Objecy.keys(list) in typescript. Have a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbhjm4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.html

Comment: The object looks like json without keys- somthing like that :["12", "firstItem"]

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
<tbody class="f">
             <ng-container *ngFor="let message of this.allMessages | filter:term | paginate: config  ;let i = index"> 
            <tr >
                <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
                    <ng-container *ngFor = "let j of this.messageIndex">
                        <td>{{message.data[0][j]}}</td>
                    </ng-container>
             </tr> 
             </ng-container> 
        </tbody>
```